# What would be the consequences of uninstalling the net-tools package in a default Ubuntu system?

Tags: networking, package-management, software-recommendation, uninstall, ip

I know that the net-tools package is deprecated and that its features are supposedly provided by the **iproute2** package.

However, I find that I keep using the old net-tools programs: it's an old habit. I want to get rid of this, and I think that uninstalling the net-tools package could help.

`apt-get remove -s net-tools` shows that the only other package to be removed would be "ubuntu-minimal", which is OK for me. I wonder if everything would keep working and if any change to system and applications network settings would then be needed.

What would be the consequences of uninstalling the net-tools package in a default Ubuntu system?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really, most of the important stuff either depends on the `iproute2` package (`ifupdown`, `isc-dhcp-client`, …) or uses the kernel interfaces (through `libnl-3-200`) directly (`network-manager`, `hostapd`, `iw`, …).

Of course some older software (especially software installed from outside of the repository) might still expect `net-tools` commands to be present as they were available on most unixoid systems for a long time. If you uninstall this package, then that is something you should keep in mind.

Anyways: I just uninstalled `net-tools` myself… No issues yet!  If something *does* happen I'll try update my answer accordingly – it's pretty unlikely through.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with the uninstall net-tools in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The Ubuntu do not use it. The system keep with network manager. Take a look:

- `ifconfig` = `ip address show` (iproute2) = `nmcli dev show` (network
  manager)
- `netstat` = nstat and rtstat (iproute2)
- `nmtui-edit` to edit all type of connection. (network manager)
- `nmtui-connect` for connect to a wifi router. (network manager)
- `nmtui-hostname` to see and change the name of machine. (network
  manager)

There is this tools in your system? If yes, probably you can remove net-tools.